# Filling a shape with color in python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to fill a shape with a color but when I run it, it does not show.
Am I not supposed to use classes for this? I am not proficient with python-3 and still learning how to use classes

```
import turtle

t=turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)


class Star(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("")
        self.color("")
#Creates the star shape    
    def shape(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.fillcolor("red")
        for i in range(9):
        self.begin_fill()
        self.left(90)
        self.forward(90)
        self.right(130)
        self.forward(90)
        self.end_fill()
#I was hoping this would fill the inside        
    def octagon(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)

    def octa(self): 
        self.fillcolor("green")
        self.begin_fill()
        self.left(25)
        for x in range(9):
            self.forward(77)
            self.right(40)

#doesn't run with out this
a=Star()
```

Answer (score 3):

Issues with your program: you create and set the speed of a turtle that you don't actually use; turtle.py already has a `shape()` method so don't override it to mean something else, pick a new name; you don't want the `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` inside the loop but rather surrounding the loop; you call your own `shape()` method with invalid arguments.

The following rework of your code addresses the above issues:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class Star(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        super().__init__(visible=False)
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.draw_star(x, y)

    def draw_star(self, x=0, y=0):
        """ Creates the star shape """

        self.penup()
        self.setposition(x, y)
        self.pendown()

        self.fillcolor("red")

        self.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(9):
            self.left(90)
            self.forward(90)
            self.right(130)
            self.forward(90)

        self.end_fill()

t = Star()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to run the program I keep getting the error: "NotImplementedError: super is not yet implemented, please report your use case as a github issue. on line 5". How do I implement super()

Comment: @geek2001, try substituting `Turtle.__init__(self, visible=False)` for  the line `super().__init__(visible=False)`.  Since you tagged your question Python-3.x, I used the newer syntax.

Comment: How do I run this in a new tab and add it to other codes?

Comment: @geek2001, I'm not certain what you're asking but based on your original code, I'm guessing the answer is, "Drop the last two lines."

Comment: I'll word it differently. Is there a way to run this in a new file without retyping all of it.

Comment: @geek2001, I understand.  Drop the last 3 lines of code (or isolate them with a `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement.)  Save this code to star.py (or whatever) and then in your other Python file do: `from star import Star`.  Then you can do `t = Star()` to generate a new star.